# Question about key establishment protocol and key exchange attack

Tags: keys, key-exchange, attack

If an adversary $M$ observes a session of the protocol between $A$ and $B$ and learns the session key $k_{AB}$.How Can the adversary mount a successful impersonation attack and communicate with $B$ on behalf of $A$?And this session are still used. Can adversary $M$ compute the key pair of $A$?

Comment: That is a type problem。Correct adversary A to M

Comment: Is the session that uses key $k_{AB}$ still active?

Comment: If you know the session key, and presuming that session key is the only key, then $M$ can do anything that $A$ can do, cryptographically speaking; decryption of messages, forging of messages, change of messages you name it. Re-authentication of the entity or renewed establishment of the secured channel is generally not possible with just a session key. What exactly is the question?

Comment: yes the Kab still active

Comment: Thanks for your help .If the adversary M can do these because they can compute the private key of A

Comment: How can M compute the private key of A

Answer (score 0):

To summarize from the comments:

> How Can the adversary mount a successful impersonation attack and communicate with B on behalf of A?

Answer:

> If you know the session key, and presuming that session key is the
>   only key, then M can do anything that A can do, cryptographically
>   speaking; decryption of messages, forging of messages, change of
>   messages you name it. Re-authentication of the entity or renewed
>   establishment of the secured channel is generally not possible with
>   just a session key. ~ [Maarten Bodewes](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/54457/question-about-key-establishment-protocol-and-key-exchange-attack#comment120537_54457)

Second Question:

> Can adversary M compute the key pair of A?

No. If you are given $(g,g^a,g^b,g^{ab})$ you cannot infer $a$ nor $b$. If you could, then you would have shown hardness-equivalence of the *Computational Diffie-Hellman Problem* (CDH) and the *Discrete Logarithm Problem* (DLOG). Because we don't know whether these two are actually equally hard, we also don't know a way to do what you asked above.